# Tool/site that converts CSS for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, plugins

Is there any website/tool that converts CSS to make it IE compatible?

Comment: no, IE is just big pain in the ass and you must suffer like the rest of us :-D write IE-specific css or make your css universal(not possible in some cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so ;) then how should the script know how it should look like? Use correct CSS and check what you can do and what is working in IE and which version.

Most Problems caused that people don't use correct CSS and have wrong elements or something else.

Here are some links for Tipps:

http://scarfoo.com/archives/16
http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/more-css-tricks.shtml

**Edit:**

You can check your CSS File with [jigsaw.w3.org](http://jigsaw.w3.org) to check if its valid.

Comment: hmmmm is their any rules that is equivalent in different browsers? So it can be standardized.

Comment: The CSS standard is the same in all browsers. The Most problem that people have is a problem with the difference of display and inline objects. When you work correct you should get the same result. You can search on google for Tipps and Tricks. When you work long enough you know what you can and do and what is very strange in a browser.

Comment: Also the lack of CSS3 support. Means that some things have browser prefixes such as -webkit -o and -moz.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much doubt it - there is no blanket rule so it would be pretty hard to automate. To make some CSS3 work in IE you could use something like css3pie.